# what are some caches that are responsible for fetching the data on miss?

Tags: caching, web-applications

The book 'architecture of open source software' says that the most common type of global cache in a web application is responsible for fetching the data itself, in case it is missing, as shown on this fixure. This seems different than what I've encountered so far. Most applications I have encountered make the application server responsible for fetching data from the db, and updating the server. At first, I thought the book might be talking about caching proxies, like Varnish, but they cover those in the next section, so that doesn't seem to be the case.

What cache systems actually fetch the data in case of a miss, and how do they know how to interact with the database?

Comment: I think it is intended that you write a cache wrapper that handles misses

Comment: I guess such a wrapper would run on the same box as the wrapper?

Comment: Completely up to you, the suggestion seems to be that you only have one route to read data. App -> Cache wrapper -> data

Answer (score 3):

Caching solutions provide read-through/write behind features which enable users to configure a read-through/write-behind provider be implementing some interface and deploying it with cache server. These providers contain logic about how cache server can interact with database to load/save data in database.

On a cache fetch operation if data is not present in cache server, cache loads data from database using configured provider thus avoiding a cache miss.

This way client applications deal cache as only data source and cache itself is responsible for interactions with database. You can read further details in [this article](http://www.alachisoft.com/resources/articles/readthru-writethru-writebehind.html) by Iqbal Khan.

[NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/) and [TayzGrid](http://www.tayzgrid.com/) are enterprise solutions among many others that provide this feature.